# SCM-manager RESTFul Web Service API to calculate ahead/behind metrics

Tags: git, scmmanager

I know the meaning of github Ahead/Behind metrics, but I am wondering if it is possible to do the calculation myself, based on te RESTFul Web Service API that SCM-manager is providing?
SCM-Manager is an easy way of sharing  your Git, Mercurial and Subversion repositories. It provides a full RESTFul Web Service API in JSON and XML.

You can find the api documentaion via [this URL](https://docs.scm-manager.org/restdocs/current/)

*Ahead is the number of commits on this branch that do not exist on the base branch. Behind is the number of commits on the base branch that do not exist on this branch.*

So somehow I have to count back the number of commits of a specific branch to the point the last merge was provided.

So how can I determine the ahead and behind status of a specific branch?
Which properties/elements do you need from Git to calculate this?

Comment: What is exactly your question? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is not a side for this. There is no question mentioned.